# Quasidiagonality and homotopy invariance: norm inequality occurring in the proof

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am reading the proof of homotopy invariance of quasi-diagonality from Brown and Ozawa (proposition 7.3.5). There is a technical part in the proof that I cannot understand. The proof is long, so I will try to include only the necessary parts.

So suppose that we have a $C^*$-algebra $B\subset B(H)$ and a finite subset $F\subset B$ and $\varepsilon>0$ is a positive quantity. It is (indeed) not hard to find a finite rank projection $q\in B(H)$ so that
$$\|qbq\|\geq\|b\|-\varepsilon $$
for all $b\in F$.

Now assume that, for some integer $n$ (that we shouldn't really worry about) we can find finite rank operators $F_0,\dots, F_n$ so that
$$q\leq F_0\leq F_1\leq F_n\leq 1_H,$$
$F_iF_{i+1}=F_i$ for all $i$ and the last one, namely $F_n$, is a projection.

We now set $G_0=F_0$, $G_1=F_1-F_0,\dots, G_n=F_n-F_{n-1}$ (which are all positive, finite rank operators) and we define an operator $$V:H\to H^{n+1},\;\;\;V\xi=(G_0^{1/2}\xi,\dots,G_n^{1/2}\xi).$$ It is not hard to verify that $V^*V=F_n$, so $V$ is a partial isometry and thus $VV^*\in B(H^{n+1})$ is a projection, we set $P=VV^*$.

Now we have a representation $\pi:B\to B(H^{n+1})$ as diagonal operators, namely $\pi(b)=(b,\rho_1(b),\dots,\rho_n(b))$ where $\rho_i:B\to B(H)$ are $*$-homomorphisms that are irrelevant to this question, I think.

The part that I do not understand is this: the authors say: "Since $F_0\geq q$, it is not hard to see that
$$\|P\pi(b)P\|\geq\|qbq\|\geq\|b\|-\varepsilon$$
for all $b\in F$." Why is the first inequality so obvious? I cannot prove it.

Doing some calculations one verifies that the matrix of $P$ is equal to $[G_i^{1/2}G_j^{1/2}]_{i,j=0}^n$ and with some calculations one sees that if $j>i+1$ then $G_i^{1/2}G_j^{1/2}=0$ (this follows from the fact that $F_iF_{i+1}=F_i$). So the matrix of $P$ is tridiagonal. I do not know if this helps, I was not able to use this in anyway.

Any ideas on what is implied here? I also looked up Voiculescu's paper and he also gives no explanation of this inequality, so I guess this follows directly from something that I cannot see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observation that is not mentioned in the book is this: since $q\leq F_j\leq 1$,
$$
\langle q\xi,q\xi\rangle=\langle q\,q\xi,q\xi\rangle\leq\langle F_j\,q\xi,q\xi\rangle\leq\langle q\xi,q\xi\rangle. 
$$
So $q(F_j-q)q=0$. Then $q(1-F_j)q=0$. As $1-F_j\geq0$, it follows that $(1-F_j)q=0$, and so $qF_j=q$. This implies that $qG_0=q$, $qG_j=0$ for all $j\geq1$.

Then
\begin{align}
\|P\pi(b)P\|
&=\|V^*\pi(b)V\|\\[0.3cm]&\geq\|qV^*\pi(b)Vq\|
=\Big\|\sum_jqG_j^{1/2}\rho_j(b)G_j^{1/2}q\Big\|\\[0.3cm]
&=\|qG_0^{1/2}bG_0^{1/2}q\|=\|G_0^{1/2}qbqG_0^{1/2}\|
=\|G_0^{1/2}qb^*qG_0qbqG_0^{1/2}\|^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&=\|G_0^{1/2}qb^*qbqG_0^{1/2}\|^{1/2}
=\|qbqG_0qb^*q\|^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&=\|qbqb^*q\|^{1/2}=\|qbq\|.
\end{align}

Comment: This is perfect, very neat manipulations, exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks. May I ask though, how does $P\geq(F_0,\dots,0)$ follow? I can see that $G_j^{1/2}G_{j\pm1}^{1/2}\geq0$, but I can't pick it up from here.

Comment: I have edited some details in.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. You have helped me very much, i really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm afraid I was wrong when checking the calculations: in the more details part, at the 2nd equation, it should be $\sum_{k,j}\langle G_k^{1/2}G_j^{1/2}\eta_j,\eta_k\rangle$. This complicates things, I have been trying to do the calculations but I cannot follow them. For example, if $n=0$ we have $$\langle P\eta,\eta\rangle=\|G_0^{1/2}\eta_0+G_1^{1/2}\eta_1\|^2=\|G_0^{1/2}\eta_0\|^2+2\text{Re}\langle G_0^{1/2}\eta_0,G_1^{1/2}\eta_1\rangle+\|G_1^{1/2}\eta_1\|^2$$ and I cannot really see why this should be greater than or equal to $\|G_0^{1/2}\eta_0\|^2$.

Comment: You said two days ago that you knew that $G_j^{1/2}G_{j\pm 1}^{1/2}\geq0$.

Comment: And I still do. What appears here are terms of the form $\langle Tx,y\rangle$, where $T$ is a positive operator. As I said, I believe there is a mistake in the 2nd equation that completely changes things from there.

Comment: Now I see what you mean.

Comment: I wrote a different answer. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Yes, this time it works like a charm. Sorry for nitpicking, but I really wanted to get to the bottom of this. Thanks again.

Comment: Finding that something is wrong is not "nitpicking"!